# All terrain crane 42082

Tags: building

The wheels don’t go round after the first book is finished. Has anyone else had this issue? What did you do to fix it?

Comment: Hi Vicky and welcome to Bricks.SE! The problem as you have described can have lots of causes, however, the ultimate cause must be a blocked axle due to a mistake in an earlier step. If you post some pictures we might be able to help you, or you can try to backtrack the offending wheel to see which axle(s) should move but refuse to. Then you'll surely find the misplaced pieces, or else you can backtrack step by step, checking the pieces added in each step and removing them if they are correct or fixing them if they aren't.